# error SQL query Invalid call to dataType on unresolved object, tree: '

Tags: sql, pyspark, databricks, databricks-sql

This is a close example of a problem.
I have a similar problem where I have to do parent first and then child join but before I add ROW_NUMBER it returns an error, I know it for sure. But the dataType problem got me thinking

I can only do SELECT and I'm using pyspark. There is also a community-written library that runs this code

`Invalid call to dataType on unresolved object, tree: '`

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UPPER(name)) AS id,
        0 as parent_id ,
        name,
        "type1" as type
    FROM sourcetable1
),
WITH cte2 AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UPPER(name))+(SELECT max(id) FROM cte1) AS id,
        cte1.id as parent_id
        name,
        "type1"  as type 
    FROM sourcetable2
    INNER JOIN cte1 ON cte1.type = sourcetable2.type and cte1.name = . sourcetable2.name 
),
WITH cte3 AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UPPER(name))+(SELECT max(id) FROM cte2) AS id,
        0 as parent_id ,
        name,
        "type2" as type
    FROM sourcetable3
),
WITH cte4 AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UPPER(name))+(SELECT max(id) FROM cte3) AS id,
        cte3.id as parent_id
        name,
        "type2"  as type 
    FROM sourcetable4
    INNER JOIN cte3 ON cte3.type = sourcetable4.type and cte3.name = . sourcetable4.name 
)


SELECT * FROM cte1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM cte2 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM cte3
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM cte4
```

Please help me!
I'm sorry if I explained it wrong :(

I tried different joining methods but they didn't like them